# MySQL - How to use JSON_EXTRACT to get values between two indices

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mariadb

I am trying to extract values between 2 indices in a JSON array using mysql JSON_EXTRACT.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[10, 20, 30, 40,50, 60]', '$[1]');
```

This query will smoothly return `20` as result. But if I want to get all the numbers between, say, 1st and 3rd indices, how do I query it?

I was expecting something like:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[10, 20, 30, 40,50, 60]', '$[1]..$[3]'); // Not the proper syntax
```

which will return `20,30,40`. But not working.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you storing data in a JSON array if you have this type of range query? It's much easier if you store data in normal rows and columns.

Comment: @BillKarwin This is sort of a temporary table. Not much processing included. Once saved, just return this data for a GET call. The only complicated processing is to get the limit and offset based retrieval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[10, 20, 30, 40,50, 60]', CONCAT('$[', idx, ']'))
FROM ( SELECT 1 idx UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 ) src;
```

Of course the indices range can be provided as list/range and converted to rowset in CTE/subquery.

Comment: I have improved the solution by making the following changes:

`SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[10, 20, 30, 40,50, 60]', CONCAT('$[', idx, ']'))
FROM ( SELECT seq as idx FROM seq_0_to_2) src;`

Note: I am using `mariadb`.

Comment: @AKA You have not marked your question with mariadb tag... next time always provide precise DBMS version in your question. And I doubt that this really improves the query - it increases its readability, of course, but does not effect the performance and decreases the compatibility.